# I would like to export below data into csv file from the multiple property files; files are not in the standard format

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

Filename: `hello1`

```
cassandraDriver.contactPoints=10.65.4.203,10.65.4.220
cassandraDriver.port=9042
```

Filename: `hello2`

```
cassandraDriver.contactPoints=10.65.4.203
cassandraDriver.port=80
onprem.cassandra.contactPoints= 10.135.83.48
cassandraDriver.port=8080

onprem.cassandra.contactPoints:10.5.14.20
```

Expected output:

```
host          port      filename
10.65.4.203   9042      hello1,hello2
10.65.4.220   9042      hello1
10.135.83.48  8080      hello2
10.5.14.20              hello2
```

Same host and port should not be repeated.

Below is the script which I have written to pull host and port

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
stty -echo
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo "\nPlease call '$0 <repo name>' to run this command!\n"
    exit 1
fi
#echo "Cloning the repository $1"
git clone ww.abc.com
cd $1
#echo "Checking the files ... "
for file in $(git ls-files);
do
    #echo  " --$file -- ";
    grep -P '((?<=[^0-9.]|^)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.([0-9]{0,3})){3}(?=[^0-9.]|$)|(http|ftp|https|ftps|sftp)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?|\.port|\.host|contact-points|contactPoints|\.uri)' $file | grep '^[^#]' | awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[2]}';
done | awk '!_[$0]++'
#echo "Done."
stty echo
cd ..
#rm -rf $1
```

Can anyone please help me to get the expected output?

Comment: There are no `adcef` "contact points", no `88934` ports, and how to deal with the "port range" (?) `8934:1234`

Comment: oops sorry, typo mistake with the port numbers, i have given just sample data instead of original

Comment: What does that output actually MEAN? Is it saying that a given port is associated with the specified host? If so why aren't there an entries for port 8934 associated with hosts 10.5.14.20 and 10.5.14.20?

Comment: Ed morton, yeah your understanding is correct

Comment: @KalpanaPinninty if my understanding is correct then your posted expected output is incorrect so please [edit] your question to correct it to be exactly the output you expect given the sample input you provided.

Comment: Why do you describe your output as CSV when you've shown it as (nearly) fixed width columns?

Comment: With your NEW data layout, where is `10.65.4.203` port `80`? Why does that FQDN show up with port 9042?

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements aren't clear but this may be what you're trying to do (using GNU awk for arrays of arrays):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]]*[,:][[:space:]]*"; OFS="\t" }
{ sub(/^[^=:]*[=:][[:space:]]*/,"") }
NR%2 { split($0,hosts); next }
{
    for (i in hosts) {
        host = hosts[i]
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            exists[host][$i][FILENAME]
        }
    }
}
END {
    print "host", "port", "filename"
    for (host in exists) {
        for (port in exists[host]) {
            printf "%s%s%s%s", host, OFS, port, OFS
            sep = ""
            for (filename in exists[host][port]) {
                printf "%s%s", sep, filename
                sep = ","
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk hello1 hello2
host    port    filename
10.12.17.18     8934    hello2
10.5.14.20      1234    hello1,hello2
10.5.14.20      8934    hello2
10.5.67.8       8934    hello2
10.11.12.203    1234    hello1
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk hello1 hello2 | column -s$'\t' -t
host          port  filename
10.12.17.18   8934  hello2
10.5.14.20    1234  hello1,hello2
10.5.14.20    8934  hello2
10.5.67.8     8934  hello2
10.11.12.203  1234  hello1
```